# How to log from Python Luigi

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, luigi

I am trying to build a strategy to log from Luigi in such a way that there is a configurable list of outputs including stdout and a custom list of files. I would like to be able to set the logging level at runtime. Our system uses Luigi to call spark from Jenkins. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside any of the Task class methods, you can do:

```
class Agg(luigi.Task):
  _date = luigi.DateParameter()

  def output(self):
    return luigi.LocalTarget("file_%.txt" % self._date)

  def run(self):
    # Use the luigi-interface to log to console
    logger = logging.getLogger('luigi-interface')
    logger.info("Running --> Agg.Task")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the **[logging_conf_file](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#core)** parameter of the configuration? you can set up there all your configuration regarding logging using Python's standard [logging mechanism](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details).

For some examples see:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/luigi-user/nKJYq_ng5y8
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/luigi-user/N83ZeePuqJk
- https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/1401

Comment: It would be really great if you could provide solutions to answers rather than links to other issue pages. The other issues and their contents are just as unhelpful.